# Reorganizing a PHP array structure (arrays within arrays)

Tags: php, array, php5

I have this array within array which contains a lot of values:

```
  183 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'DE' (length=2)
      1 => string '2015-06-09' (length=10)
      2 => string 'GK' (length=2)   
  184 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'DE' (length=2)
      1 => string '2015-06-08' (length=10)
      2 => string 'GL' (length=2)   
  185 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'FR' (length=2)
      1 => string '2015-06-09' (length=10)
      2 => string 'GN' (length=2)   
  186 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'FR' (length=2)
      1 => string '2015-09-08' (length=10)
      2 => string 'GO' (length=2)
```

0 is the country code. 1 is a date. 2 is a column on an Excel file.

I want to organize it in this way:

```
2015-06-09 => 
  array (size=3)
    DE => 
      array (size=2)
        column => GK
        download => 666 
    FR => 
      array (size=2)
        column => GN
        download => 777 

2015-06-08 =>
  array (size=3)
    DE => 
      array (size=2)
        column => GL
        download => 666 
    FR => 
      array (size=2)
        column => GO
        download => 777
```

So the same date can show up more than once. if it gets to an array value with the same date - it inserts in it the country code with and its' column.

if it has more than 1 country - it adds a new country. (with the 'download' and column values).

I have this function:

```
function get_cols_to_array_by_date($array) { 

    $mainarr = array();

    $last_in_arr = count($array); 

    for ($i=0; $i<$last_in_arr; $i++){

            $mainarr[$array[$i][1]] = array( $array[$i][0]=> array('downloads'=> 666, 'col'=>$array[$i][2]) );


    }

    return $mainarr;


}
```

which outputs an array that runs over the country when it gets to the same date and doesn't give me an array of countries.

What part am I missing in my code? 
Is there a simpler way to do it? ( PHP syntax shortcuts ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why

You're replacing the indexed item for the date when you declare a new array in the line:

`$mainarr[$array[$i][1]] = array( $array[$i][0]=> array('downloads'=> 666, 'col'=>$array[$i][2]) );`

See it as `$array[$index] = array(...)` -- running it again over the same index would replace the value at that index.

## Quick Fix

You could simply replace that line with (considering that there'll not be more than one line for a given country, for the same date, as in: no two DE for 2015-06-08):

```
if (!isset($mainarr[$array[$i][1]])) { $mainarr[$array[$i][1]] = array(); }
$mainarr[$array[$i][1]][$array[$i][0]] = array('downloads'=> 666, 'col'=>$array[$i][2]);
```

Note that `$array[$i][0]` (aka the country) moved to the left site of `=`, and the outer array on the right side of it was removed.

## How would I do

I refactored the code to be more legible and easier to understand, and also use better practices IMHO:

```
function get_cols_to_array_by_date($array) { 
    // set the name of the variable to a more meaningful one
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $i => $data) {
        // shortcuts to prevent having to remember which index they are (you could change them for constants)
        $country = $data[0];
        $date = $data[1];
        $col = $data[2];

        $download = 123; // don't know where 'download' value comes from, put it here

        // you need to check if the date index already exists
        // if not, create the empty array for the date
        if (!isset($result[$date])) {
            $result[$date] = array();
        }

        // considering that country will NOT repeat for a given date
        $result[$date][$country] = array(
            'column' => $col,
            'download' => $download,
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```